# Mocking a FileStream constructor within a Web API

Tags: c#, rest, mocking, moq, mstest

I have the following piece of code within the POST method of my REST API:

```
using (FileStream outputFile = new FileStream(Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
```

The problem now is that I want to mock the FileStream object but I have no clue how because I cannot inject the object through my constructor. When I do that I get the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.IO.FileStream' while attempting to activate 'webservice.Controllers.DataController'.

I also cannot add a layer of abstraction for the constructor of the FileStream object.

Does any of you have some experience with this and if yes, could you help me? Because the 2 ways above are all I can find on google sadly and I rather not write files to my file system while unit testing for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create files with FileStream, then you have to remove this class from your Controller. One approach would be creating some thing like `IFileSystemHelper` with for example `SaveFileData` method like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using System.IO;

    public interface IFileSystemHelper
    {
        void SaveFileData(string fileLocation, string fileName);
    }

    public class FileSystemHelper : IFileSystemHelper
    {
        public void SaveFileData(string fileLocation, string fileName)
        {
            using (FileStream outputFile = new FileStream(Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                // TODO: Save file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Than you can easily inject this helper to your controller, and then mock it and test.